# How does false == (x > y) work?

Tags: javascript

I read this in a book and was just wondering how it works and if you would ever do something like that and for what reason you would do that. I understand you could return `(x>y)` but why would you do `false == (x > y)`?

Comment: *"If `x` is not greater than `y`".* That's kind of a backwards way of writing `x <= y`, but why not?

Comment: [**Yoda condition**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) it is... :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a more verbose way of writing

```
x <= y
```

The result of `x > y` is evaluated and compared to `false`. Since the result of `x > y` is boolean, that's the same as writing

```
!(x > y)  // an == true is implied here if you don't add it yourself
```

which of course is the same as writing

```
x <= y
```

Answer (score 1):

- `if(x <= y)`
- `if(!(x > y))`
- `if((x>y) == false)`

They all evaluate to the same condition. It's just different ways of writing. I usually prefer to use the more readable ones.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have three variable and all takes binary value.We can use this for implementing some results.Like this.

ex : if(a==(b>c)) represents first scenario.

```
 A   B    C
 0   0    0
 0   0    1
 0   1    0
 0   1    1
 1   0    0
 1   0    1
 1   1    0
 1   1    1
```

Comment: Your answer, although informative, misses the point of this question. There are only 2 variable in play here, and OP is unsure about an oddly stated evaluation.

Comment: you are correct but if we have to use two operator == & >.we should hav 3 variable like conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a common construct to put the immutable values on the left of the == and variables on the right.
This is in case you accidentally miss out one of the equals signs. This way the compiler will highlight your error.

For example were you to accidentally type

if(a = true){...}

this would always execute the code inside the braces as it sets the value of a to true.

However if you were to accidentally type

if(true = a){...}

The compiler should alert you since you cannot change the value of true

Though in this particular example there are much better ways of writing the expression without the need for double equals signs (see all the previous answers)